# SQL: Remove top 4 records from table

Tags: sql, ms-access

i currently do have a table called TempTable imported from excel sheet. However, how can i make use of vba code to remove the top four records as they are unnecessary data. i know "SELECT TOP 4 * FROM TempTable" does the select job. But how do i do delete? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: show table structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT TOP 4 * FROM TempTable)
```

*Just in case make sure you a backup before you delete*

Answer (score 1):

In SQL server 2008 and later you can do it in this way same as select .

```
DELETE TOP(4) FROM TempTable
```

Thanks

Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate

```
SET ROWCOUNT 4
DELETE FROM TempTable
```